# Can I execute MySQL SQL statements in FireFox?

Tags: mysql, database, firefox, greasemonkey

There is a FireFox plugin called `greasemonkey` with which you can execute some piece of JavaScript code on the page you specified. I want to know whether there is a way that I can embed SQL statements (MySQL) in JavaScript. If so, I can extract the information I need and save them to my MySQL database for later use. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You could create a simple script on your server that will pass through SQL statements, but this is probably a bad idea since eventually someone will try to mess with your server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you cannot execute MySQL statements in Firefox, although [you can in Chrome for the moment](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/).

In Firefox you can [create and use IndexedDB databases](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/) -- a more supported browser-DB approach (that is actually in the HTML5 spec).  This might be enough, depending on your ultimate goal.

For full, traditional, DB support, you will have to write a web interface...

1. You can host such an interface on any machine using something like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). (Or use the language of your choice.)
2. Send your data from the Greasemonkey script to the web-app, using `GM_xmlhttpRequest`, like so:

   ```
   var myData      = {strVar: 'Hiya!', intVar: 777, etc: 'et cetera'};
   var DataForDB   = JSON.stringify (myData);

   GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
       method:     "POST",
       url:        "http://localhost/YourDir/LogMyData.php",
       data:       DataForDB,
       headers:    {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
   } )
   ```
3. A PHP webpage would extract the data like so:

   ```
   $myData = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
   print_r ($myData);
   ```
4. The web page then interacts with mySQL as you see fit, returning any desired values to the GM script.

Answer (score 0):

No, the process must be done using a server-side language, such as PHP. Javascript is a client-side language.